# Load the component when all data has ready

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm using React with Redux.
In this example I have my class with **mapStateToProps** and **mapDispatchToProps**

```
class EnigmaPage extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.authCheckState();
    }

    readUserData() {
        this.props.loadLevel(this.props.userId);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className={classes.EnigmaPage}>
                <div className={classes.Header}>
                    <div>
                        <LevelInfo 
                            difficulty={this.props.level.difficulty}
                            level={this.props.level.level}
                            readUserData={this.readUserData()}
                        />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        authCheckState: () => dispatch(actions.authCheckState()),
        getLevel: () => dispatch(actions.getLevel()),
        loadLevel:(id) => dispatch(actions.loadLevel(id))
    };
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        userId:state.auth.user,
        level:state.level.level
    }
}
```

I wanna push to my component **LevelInfo** the values **difficulty** and **level** but these 2 data arrive from **getLevel()** that is an http request with delay.
The page loads before receiving all the data from the http call.
I'm looking a way to wait to load the component **LevelInfo** or reload the component when the data are all ready.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to tell your component that will wait for the data needed to render your `Level` component, so into your `EnigmaPage` component write as follow

```
render(){
    const { level } = this.props;
    if (!level) { return <LoadingComponentSpinner />; } // this will render only when level attr is not set, otherwise will render your `LevelInfo` component
    return (
        <div className={classes.EnigmaPage}>
            <div className={classes.Header}>
                <div>
                    <LevelInfo 
                        difficulty={this.props.level.difficulty}
                        level={this.props.level.level}
                        readUserData={this.readUserData()}
                    />

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I hope it can help you.

Comment: Voted for the spinner example where i was lazy for my answer :)

Comment: Great one, you should always let the user know, what is happing with the app state, so spinner is a great manner to tell our user that we'll waiting for data :D

Comment: Sure. But life is too short to write a complete, detailed example in the middle of the night :D

Comment: @JohuderGonzalez thanks for your answer but in this case there are ever the spinner. I need to load my component LevelInfo when is ready. When I load the page, all the props is not ready and it load LoadingComponentSpinner. When is done stop the flow in this case.

Comment: @MarcoPestrin the Issue is that you are executing the loadLevel function into your LevelVomponent so execute that function in componentDidMount into your EnigmaPage component, that will do the trick

Comment: So remember to remove execution of readUserData into your LevelInfo Component to avoid executing twice.

Answer (score 2):

We don't make our components wait, we let the initial rendering happens but render the target component with a conditional expression.

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className={classes.EnigmaPage}>
      <div className={classes.Header}>
        <div>
          {this.props.level && (
            <LevelInfo
              difficulty={this.props.level.difficulty}
              level={this.props.level.level}
              readUserData={this.readUserData()}
            />
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

So, here we are checking if `this.props.level` is defined. When it is `undefined` React does not render anything, after getting the data `LevelInfo` component is rendered. You can change conditional rendering logic. You can render a `Loading` component maybe instead of nothing. But, at the end of the day, you will render your component conditionally.

Comment: but in this case when all the props is ready the LevelInfo component will not load.

Comment: @MarcoPestrin, when a component's props changed React re-renders it. In this second render since you have the `this.props.level` prop, (so, the first condition is true) the expression goes the second part, hence your `LevelInfo` component is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html):

```
isDataReady() {
    if(this.props.level.difficulty && this.props.level.level)
        return true;
    return false;
}

render(){
    return (
        <div className={classes.EnigmaPage}>
            <div className={classes.Header}>
                <div>
                {this.isDataReady() ? <LevelInfo 
                        difficulty={this.props.level.difficulty}
                        level={this.props.level.level}
                        readUserData={this.readUserData()}
                    />
             : <div> </div>}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

in case your data is not ready you can display anything you want, for simplicity here I just added an empty `<div>`.

Answer (score 0):

Johuder Gonzalez has talked about the Spinner. The Material UI has a lot of examples, which is easy to apply. Please look the followings.
[Material UI Progress](https://material-ui.com/demos/progress/)